# How to cite a URL in Latex if I do not write explicitly the URL?

Tags: urls, urlbst

I want to cite a URL with name IIT Kharagpur but when I click on the hyperlink it should open the link www.iitkgp.ac.in in my browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the package hyperref to perform this task. Is that what you are looking for?

```
    \documentclass[11pt]{article}
    \usepackage{hyperref}

    \begin{document}
    \href{www.iitkgp.ac.in}{IIT Kharagpur}
    \end{document}
```

> [Source](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/148691/inserting-a-clickable-url-into-moderncv-not-working-anymore)